# How do I rewrite $x = $hash{blah} || 'default' in Python?

Tags: python

How do I pull an item out of a Python dictionary without triggering a KeyError? In Perl, I would do:

```
$x = $hash{blah} || 'default'
```

What's the equivalent Python?

Comment: For the record, your Perl is a bit iffy. If $hash{blah} is 0 or "" or "0" it won't work. You should use the // (defined-OR) operator instead. It won't go to the 'default' unless the first argument is undefined instead of just false.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the [`get(key, default)`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) method:

```
>>> dict().get("blah", "default")
'default'
```

Answer (score 7):

If you're going to be doing this a lot, it's better to use [collections.defaultdict](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
import collections

# Define a little "factory" function that just builds the default value when called.
def get_default_value():
  return 'default'

# Create a defaultdict, specifying the factory that builds its default value
dict = collections.defaultdict(get_default_value)

# Now we can look up things without checking, and get 'default' if the key is unknown
x = dict['blah']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
x = hash['blah'] if 'blah' in hash else 'default'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x = hash.has_key('blah') and hash['blah'] or 'default'
```